# WCF service returning "is undefined" in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, undefined

When this JavaScript code is run, it tells me that "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'InputService' is undefined".

I have tried and tried, and I just can't seem to figure out of what I am missing...

Web.Config file (just the web service part):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CommonEndPointBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="InputService">
        <endpoint name="" address="" behaviorConfiguration="CommonEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="InputService" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <!--<security mode="Transport">-->
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The Service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class InputService
{
[OperationContract]
public string EditSiteElement(int siteid, string name, string url, string description, int siteorder, bool active)
{
    return Input.EditSiteElement(siteid, name, url, description, siteorder, active);
}
}
```

The references in the web form:

```
    scriptManagerProxy.Services.Add(new ServiceReference("~/User/Input.svc"));
    scriptManagerProxy.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference("~/User/Input.js"));
```

JavaScript file:

```
//When edit button is clicked on row.
function EditSiteElement(siteid) {
    InputService.GetSiteIdInfo(siteid, function (result) {
        var stuff = result.split('¤');
        $('[id$=TextBox_name]').val(stuff[0]);
        $('[id$=TextBox_link]').val(stuff[1]);
        $('[id$=TextBox_description]').val(stuff[2]);
        $('[id$=CheckBox_active]').prop('checked', (stuff[3] == 'True'));
        $('[id$=TextBox_order]').val(stuff[4]);
        //Open the dialog
        $("[id$=panel_Input]").dialog('open');

        SiteIdForSave = siteid;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of changes you have to do.

First, decorate the service method with the `WebInvoke` attribute which resides in the `System.ServiceModel.Web` namespace (you may have to add the reference to your project).

```
[OperationContract]
[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke] //add this attribute
public string EditSiteElement(int siteid, string name, string url, string description, int siteorder, bool active)
{
    return Input.EditSiteElement(siteid, name, url, description, siteorder, active);
}
```

Second, in the `InputService.svc` file (in Visual Studio, right click on the `InputService.svc` file and select `View Markup`), add the `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"` attribute:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" Service="WebApplication6.InputService" CodeBehind="InputService.svc.cs" %>
```

Make sure that the target framework version for your application is **4.5**.

**[EDIT]**

I suggest you modify the `web.config`'s `<system.serviceModel>` section as follows. Please pay attention to the use of your namespaces (`MyNamespace`) and to the fact that I moved the behavior definition from the end point to the service level.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="InputServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="InputServiceBehavior" name="MyNamespace.InputService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.InputService" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webBinding">
        <!--<security mode="Transport">-->
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I have done the same thing at work before, but we did not have to set the method as static or instantiate the object in JavaScript. I think this may not be the path to the correct solution...

Comment: Still no joy :( I feel like i may be missing a simple little thing... i am currently comparing my project vs the one at work, and they are totally alike (as when described above...) I cant help think that i am missing a small piece of the puzzle....

Comment: Yes... and it is still not working... What i find strange is that if i try on a new test project. i Create one webform or aspx site. I create one service, it adds some stuff to the web.config file, and i add the endpoint, i add the service reference to the aspx file through the scriptmanager, and i create a javascript file that calls this service.. should this not be enough? i can not understand why it would be necessary to set them as webinvoke, webscriptservicehostfactory ++... especially when it works on the solution we use at work.....

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen, have you verified the last statement regarding the target framework in my answer?

Comment: It is 4.5... i have made a couple of new project to test out my thesis, and in every one of them i experience the same problem.. I have shown it to one of my colleagues today and we will hopefully resolve the issue... He could not understand what was wrong at first glance.. so i guess it's not to obvious what i've done wrong... :(